# how to log OUTGOING https requests from node within webstorm

Tags: node.js, https, webstorm

I'm hacking together some node.js code that calls an external webservice and I'm getting bad results.  I'd like to log the raw request and response so that I can inspect it.

Here's the thing:  **I'm not consuming the http library directly**, I'm consuming it through an OAuth library.

I'm already adding debug statements in the oauth library code and I don't like it.  Now it looks like I'm going to have to go into http library and start messing with that?  This can't be correct.

If I was on windows, I'd fire up fiddler.  A friend mentioned wireshark but wireshark tells me I have to install X11.  Really?  I'm not going down that rabbit hole.

Then I tried node-inspector, but I think that is for server code not client code.  It says your suppose to start your node process before attaching.  Well my node process is a test case (vows) that ends shortly after is starts... so no luck there.

I guess this would difficult with any stack but jeez, it makes me miss .net!

So, how can I inspect what's going over the wire when using node.js as client to external webservice on mountain lion?

thanks!
Dan

Comment: Did you ever find any luck on this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Managed to install a hook on `http`/`https` request for the same reason.

```
function requestLogger(httpModule){
    var original = httpModule.request
    httpModule.request = function(options, callback){
      console.log(options.href||options.proto+"://"+options.host+options.path, options.method)
      return original(options, callback)
    }
}

requestLogger(require('http'))
requestLogger(require('https'))
```

Comment: Note that using this method will log twice for https requests, since https.request() just delegates to http.request(). Just add the logging to "http", and guess the protocol by testing if "options._defaultAgent" exists (which is set in "https.request()").

Comment: Isn't `options.proto` enough to detect if the request is using http or https ?

Comment: I had to use `options.url || options.protocol + '://' + options.hostname + options.path,`  in node 10

Comment: is there a way to get the request body with this solution?

Answer (score 8):

You can check out the [global-request-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-request-logger) module, which uses the same technique that @uiron mentioned, but with more details.

Comment: As of 2023, this library is deprecated and the repo seems deleted.