# Node.js / express / passport / saml - How to inspect the content of outgoing HTTP request to SAML Identity Provider?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, saml

I am a newbie in node.js, but I have a sample application written for node.js that shows the way of integration with specific Identity Provider (SAML). Using this sample app I am trying to inspect what is sent in the HTTP requests made from the node.js backend to the remote IdP. Logging the request headers and body by writing to the console.log would be enough for me. Monitoring the network traffic with some tool like Fiddler is not an option for me, because I cannot run it locally, I need to have the app exposed and I have it deployed to Heroku.

I've tried morgan, but it only intercepts the INCOMING requests. I've also tried global-request-logger, but for some reason it does not inject itself into the express framework and passport. Seems like passport is not using the standard modules for HTTP requests?

The question is: what I need to use to be able to log the content of the HTTP requests made by passport during the .authenticate() call? Is there any flag that I am able to set in passport to enable HTTP logging? Or should I rather do it in express? Or maybe some other package would provide the functionality I need?

EDIT: 
My original question was marked as possible duplicate of [how to log OUTGOING https requests from node within webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964517/how-to-log-outgoing-https-requests-from-node-within-webstorm)

But actually I have already seen that topic and I've tried to setup a hook to http module, it was done this way:

```
'use strict';

// Setup express.js application:
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Patch "http" module with outgoing request logging:
var http = require('http');
const originalRequest = http.request;
http.request = function wrapMethodRequest(req) {
    console.log('EXTERNAL OUTGOING REQUEST LOGGING:');
    console.log(req.host, req.body);
    return originalRequest.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

This approach was not working. As already said in the original question, it seems that passport does not use standard http module? Or did I something wrong with the code above? 
As already mentioned in the original question, I was also trying to handle it via global-request-logger package (which as explained in the possible duplicated post, uses the same technique). The code for that was:

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var app = express();    
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));    
var globalLog = require('global-request-logger');
globalLog.initialize();    
globalLog.on('success', (req, res) => {
    console.log('HTTP(S) CALLOUT SUCCESS');
    console.log('REQUEST: ', req);
    console.log('RESPONSE: ', res);
});    
globalLog.on('error', (req, res) => {
    console.log('HTTP(S) CALLOUT ERROR');
    console.log('REQUEST: ', req);
    console.log('RESPONSE: ', res);
});
...
```

Comment: @AndyTaton I've explained why I think it is not a duplicate and added some code samples.

Comment: I flagged before thinking through the whole story, apologies. I think the `passport-saml` library uses HTTP Redirect binding, which means the identity provider isn't making any http requests of its own. (You can see this in the library's [`saml.js`](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml/blob/master/lib/passport-saml/saml.js), in its redirect formatting methods.) SAML XML is packaged in the redirect response to the client req.